# Missing required parameters for Route in vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to call only the Data with one user ID only:
and i get the below error:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: VLead] [URI: VLead/{id}]. (View: C:\wamp64\www\S2\resources\views\admin\sidebar\sidebar.blade.php) (View: C:\wamp64\www\S2\resources\views\admin\sidebar\sidebar.blade.php)
```

```
Route::get('/VLead/{id}', 'ClientController@index_lead')->name('VLead')->middleware('user');
```

Controller

```
public function index_lead($id)
   {
     $clients = DB::table('clients')->where('Stage','<>',"Active" )
                                    ->orderBy('id', 'Aesc')
                                    ->get();
      return view('admin.VLead',compact('clients'));
   }
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
          var scrt_var = {{ Sentinel::getuser()->id}}; 
</script>
```

```
<li><a class="" href="{{route('VLead')}} "onclick="location.href=this.href+'/'+scrt_var;return false;" >Leads</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `{{route('VLead')}}` to `{{route('VLead', Sentinel::getuser()->id)}}` or make the `id` parameter optional by changing `Route::get('/VLead/{id}'` to `Route::get('/VLead/{id?}'`

Comment: Check the javascript console for errors, the css might not be loading in. Also please go ahead and accept my answer as the accepted one if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because you do not pass required parameter. Do something like this:

```
{{ route('VLead', ['id' => $userId]) }}
```